# How to upload files with DRF and React?

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, axios

I'm learning Django Rest Framework, everything was going well until I had to create a service to upload files to my application.As much as I read the documentation, I can't understand it.
First I want to clarify that I am not a programming expert, I am a
newbie but I am here learning more every day.
From what I've managed to understand so far:
Documents and photos are not stored in the database. These files are stored in a folder.

This is correct ?

I have a form where it allows me to upload multiple files
example:

file.txt, document.doc, photo.png etc...

## My view (Frontend):

```
import { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const Form = () => {
  const [state_files, setState_Files] = useState(null);

  const UploadFiles = function (event) {
    setState_Files(event);
  };

  const InsertFiles = async function () {
    const formData = new FormData();
    for (let index = 0; index < state_files.length; index++) {
      formData.append("files", state_files[index]);
    }

    await axios
      .post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/upload/", formData)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
  return (
    <>
      <input
        type="file"
        name="files"
        multiple
        onChange={() => InsertFiles(event.target.files)}
      />
      <button>Upload All files</button>
    </>
  );
};

export default Form;
```

### Backend

#### url.py

```
path("upload/", Storage_View.as_view(), name="storage-index"),
```

#### storage/view.py

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.parsers import MultiPartParser


class Storage_View(APIView):
    parser_classes = [MultiPartParser]

    def put(self, request, filename, format=None):
        file_obj = request.data['file']
        # ...
        # What do I have to do here?
        # ...
        return Response({'received data': request.data})
```

## Questions:

1. Why don't I see the button to upload files using the DFR tool? see attached files

[image]

2. The documentation does not explain what I have to do inside the function comment
   https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/
   `def put(...):`
3. How do I specify the path where you have to store the files you upload?

Please I need guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1: show your models for more detail. you have to use filefield or
> imagefield in your model. You can google and read more about these
> fields.
>
> 2: put is for update, write your post method to save data. You don't
> have to really do anything serious there. just check if
> serializer.is_Valid() for request.data and if valid do
> serializer.save(). the file or image will be uploaded to upload_to
> folder which you define in your model and you will get the link.
>
> 3: read more about upload_to in Django. you can define this with the
> model field.

I used ModelViewSet and this is how the create method looks like -

```
def create(self, request, format=None):
    data = request.data
    if isinstance(data, list):  # <- is the main logic
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data, many=True)
    else:
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

You are passing a list from frontend and by default, Django works on dictionary, so you will have to manage this. Think of this as your go to code and write your post method.

Feel free to write more if you have doubts, Hope this helps :)